# Как установить disabled=true сразу для нескольких селекторов

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Подскажите пожалуйста, как отключить disabled=true - сразу для нескольких селекторов в которых имеется класс .inchange

Пример кода:

```js
// Отключение
$(document).ready(function() {
    // plus minus
    $("#cci-edit-change").click(function(){
      document.querySelector('inchange').disabled = false;
    });
});

// Подсчет
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.minus').click(function () {
        var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
        var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 10;
        count = count < 0 ? 0 : count;
        $input.val(count);
        $input.change();
        return false;
    });
    $('.plus').click(function () {
        var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
        $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 10);
        $input.change();
        return false;
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity d-flex justify-align-center">
    <button class="minus inchange" disabled=""> - </button>
    <input type="text" class="value t-15 " value="300" min="0" step="10" onchange="quantity(event)" disabled="">
    <button class="plus " disabled=""> + </button>
</div>

<div class="cci-edit" id="cci-edit-change"> отключить </div>
```

Спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
// Отключение
$(document).ready(function() {
  // plus minus
  $("#cci-edit-change").click(function() {
    $('.inchange').prop('disabled', true);
  });
});

// Подсчет
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.minus').click(function() {
    var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
    var count = parseInt($input.val()) - 10;
    count = count < 0 ? 0 : count;
    $input.val(count);
    $input.change();
    return false;
  });
  $('.plus').click(function() {
    var $input = $(this).parent().find('input');
    $input.val(parseInt($input.val()) + 10);
    $input.change();
    return false;
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="quantity d-flex justify-align-center">
  <button class="minus inchange"> - </button>
  <input type="text" class="value t-15 " value="300" min="0" step="10" disabled>
  <button class="plus inchange"> + </button>
</div>

<div class="cci-edit" id="cci-edit-change"> отключить </div>
```